# Get registered domains by python

Tags: python, list, dns

I want to make a python program on whois domain.

I want to obtain the information that is registered every day in whois domain.

look for there is a [whois library](https://pypi.org/project/python-whois/).

but it seems that you cannot search the domains obtained every day.

is there a way to get the domains each day that they are registered?

if someone knows can teach me please.

code expamle imformation domain

```
import whois

w = whois.whois('https://qiita.com/')

print(w)
```

out put

```
{
  "domain_name": [
    "QIITA.COM",
    "qiita.com"
  ],
  "registrar": "Amazon Registrar, Inc.",
  "whois_server": "whois.registrar.amazon.com",
  "referral_url": null,
  "updated_date": [
    "2021-06-13 23:21:43",
    "2021-06-13 23:21:44.397000"
  ],
  "creation_date": "2011-07-18 11:47:04",
  "expiration_date": "2022-07-18 11:47:04",
  "name_servers": [
    "NS-1049.AWSDNS-03.ORG",
    "NS-171.AWSDNS-21.COM",
    "NS-1956.AWSDNS-52.CO.UK",
    "NS-772.AWSDNS-32.NET",
    "ns-1049.awsdns-03.org",
    "ns-171.awsdns-21.com",
    "ns-1956.awsdns-52.co.uk",
    "ns-772.awsdns-32.net"
  ],
  "status": [
    "clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited",
    "renewPeriod https://icann.org/epp#renewPeriod"
  ],
  "emails": [
    "abuse@amazonaws.com",
    "owner-10471934@qiita.com.whoisprivacyservice.org",
    "admin-10471934@qiita.com.whoisprivacyservice.org",
    "tech-10471934@qiita.com.whoisprivacyservice.org"
  ],
  "dnssec": "unsigned",
  "name": "On behalf of qiita.com owner",
  "org": "Whois Privacy Service",
  "address": "P.O. Box 81226",
  "city": "Seattle",
  "state": "WA",
  "zipcode": "98108-1226",
  "country": "US"
}
```

Is there a way as it appears in the output "creation date" to be able to search the registered domains of today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to get the domains each day that they are registered?

No, or not in general. It depends on the TLD.

- for gTLDs, you can retrieve zonefiles daily from ICANN CZDS; if you collect two of them one day apart the "difference" is the new domains, with some caveats (not all domains appear in zonefile)
- some registries do provide this data directly, albeit not necessarily in easy to use form; this is one example: https://www.afnic.fr/en/products-and-services/fr-and-associated-services/shared-data-reuse-fr-data/
- some registrars may offer this kind of feature, so it will depend on their API.

Also, you should use RDAP, not whois.

Comment: Thanks for the message. Daily list of registered domain names is it no more from France? There is no way to see from other countries I want to see the list of Japan. I search the internet for zonefiles it can but it is not free. If there is another page, can you show me? sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: gTLDs provide zonefiles (daily, for free), as they are required to do so by their contract with ICANN. ccTLDs are far more restrictive considering it is private data, so it is almost never available directly from registries (but for research needs and the sort, you can ask them directly). Various other companies can claim offering that service (for a fee), when they themselves collect daily data and collate it, or other undisclosed means. But in short, what you want mostly doesn't exist in ccTLDs. It also depends on *why* do you want to do such kind of search, by day of registration.

Comment: Thanks for the message. I intend to sign up for zone files, but I don't know if that page is reliable. Does it have a contract with ICANN?
How do you know that ? if you know you can teach me.

Comment: Just go to https://czds.icann.org/ and read everything, especially the contract that you will have to sign that restricts what you can do with the data you will be able to collect. This is only for gTLDs again. ICANN is the top body organizing the domains world and with whom all gTLD registries and registrars are under contract. I am not sure exactly on which page you are talking about. Again, for gTLDs you have zonefiles through ICANN program, and for ccTLDs you have to search on each registry what they offer or not, but in 99% of cases you won't get access to zonefiles there.